# How can I extract this cookie consent slider?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cookie

I like the red corner cookie constent for this website below, and I have tried all means to use it, does any one know how to extract it?

https://www.metalbulletin.com/Article/3831445/Cobalt/Investors-should-focus-on-battery-materials-not-EVs-Blackstone-Resources-CEO.html?ArticleId=3831445

If no one can, where can I get good looking cookie consents like this?

Comment: try this $('.cookieAccepterSlider') if your using jQuery, or simply inspect the element.

Comment: Javed, I tried everything it did not work, please try it and let me know if it works

Comment: My bad, please clarify what exactly you mean by ''extract it''?

Comment: I need the full code to use it on my website. the javascript and the html, I tried everything I could not get it.